# downside of a production webpack web-server while deploying Vue applications

Tags: webpack, vue.js, deployment

I'm building a Vue application with the webpack template.
So far everything looks good but I have a question about deploying.

When I run `npm run dev` webpack starts automatically a web-server, so that I just need to go to the specified address to see the application running.
When I run `npm run build` webpack bundles everything and then injected the link to the bundled css/js/whatever file into the `dist/index.html`.

My question is: why the production script doesn't start a web server like the development one? I think it would simplify the deploy process and I can't really see any downside...

Info about the webpack template: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

Comment: The webserver started in development is not meant to be used as a production server.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major downsides I see right off the bat:

- No minification and perfomance issues: The code that gets delivered will be huge instead of just a small bundle. Also you'll have things like babel, eslint and hot reloading running all the time in the background when they're not needed.
- Deployment must happen on a Node.JS server, while when you bundle it pretty much any server can deploy the bundle, as those are only html, css and javascript files.

Comment: The minification can still happen, the build script can just serve automatically the /dist/index.html file...
For the second point I actually haven't thought about it, you would need a node server to run webpack web-server!

Comment: The minification can still happen but you'll still have unnecessary perfomance drains from things like hot reloading. I highly suggest using the bundled files.